# Can I retrieve house number on mapbox reverse geocoder?

Tags: mapbox

Currently when I would like to retrieve address for coordinates I make following request as an example:

`GET http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy/geocode/-114.0701,51.0495.json`

I get address information up to the street level but NO house number. Is there way to retrieve it as well? I think it's such an obvious need and cannot think of any problems extracting this date when you already extracted the rest.

```
{
    "attribution": {
        "mapbox-places": "<a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/' target='_blank'>&copy; Mapbox &copy; OpenStreetMap</a> <a class='mapbox-improve-map' href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a>"
    },
    "query": [
        -114.0701,
        51.0495
    ],
    "results": [
        [
            {
                "id": "street.31973701",
                "lat": 51.0476559,
                "lon": -114.0703042,
                "name": "3 St SW",
                "type": "street"
            },
            {
                "bounds": [
                    -114.36183200000002,
                    50.84361600000001,
                    -113.87432100000002,
                    51.217528999999985
                ],
                "id": "mapbox-places.10008775",
                "lat": 51.03095,
                "lon": -114.108491,
                "name": "Calgary",
                "type": "city"
            },
            {
                "bounds": [
                    -120.00138351899996,
                    48.99667665000002,
                    -110.004763853,
                    60.00042158400004
                ],
                "id": "province.2553712403",
                "lat": 54.872006,
                "lon": -115.003552,
                "name": "Alberta",
                "type": "province"
            },
            {
                "bounds": [
                    -141.00275000000013,
                    40.043430830999895,
                    -47.69751888999983,
                    86.45371111000011
                ],
                "id": "country.1833980151",
                "lat": 76.304456,
                "lon": -105.801333,
                "name": "Canada",
                "type": "country"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Mapbox doesn't have this level of data. You would need to use a better mapping provider to get this kind of data.

Comment: Is this result different than what you get using the geocode endpoint [here](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=cURL#retrieve-places-near-a-location)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rbrundritt is correct.

Most mapping applications (Google, Bing, etc) merely [interpolate the location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding#Address_interpolation) when given a street address.  They are aware of the starting and ending address on a given block and then make an educated guess as to where the address you are search for is located on that block based on that.  They don't actually store the outlines and the addresses of each property.